# Apache Spark driver logs don't specify reason of stage cancelling

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I run Apache Spark on AWS EMR under YARN.
The cluster has 1 master and 10 executors.
After some hours of processing my cluster failed and I go to look on a log.

So, I see that all working executors were trying to kill task at one time (It's the log of someone executor):

```
20/03/05 00:02:12 INFO Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 66.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 466), reason: Stage cancelled
20/03/05 00:02:12 INFO Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 65.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 465), reason: Stage cancelled
20/03/05 00:02:12 INFO Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 67.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 467), reason: Stage cancelled
20/03/05 00:02:12 INFO Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 64.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 464), reason: Stage cancelled
20/03/05 00:02:12 ERROR Utils: Aborting a task
```

I see that reason is `Stage cancelled` but I can't get any details about that. I see driver logs and find that they have the last record at much earlier time.

So I have 2 questions:

- Why driver logs are much shorter than executors logs?
- How can I get the real reason why stage cancelled?

```
20/03/04 18:39:40 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 159.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 359, ip-172-31-6-236.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 40, partition 159, RACK_LOCAL, 8421 bytes)
20/03/04 18:39:40 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: New executor 40 has registered (new total is 40)
20/03/04 18:39:41 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager ip-172-31-6-236.us-west-2.compute.internal:33589 with 2.8 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(40, ip-172-31-6-236.us-west-2.compute.internal, 33589, None)
20/03/04 18:39:42 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on ip-172-31-6-236.us-west-2.compute.internal:33589 (size: 44.7 KB, free: 2.8 GB)
20/03/04 18:39:48 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on ip-172-31-6-236.us-west-2.compute.internal:33589 (size: 37.4 KB, free: 2.8 GB)
```